# Adding custom rules to sonar PMD written using Java Way

Tags: pmd, sonarqube

I'm using Sonar v3.5.1 & PMD V4.3 and I want to add custom rules to my PMD runner written in Java.

How should I add new rules to the `pmd-rules.xml` configuration file, so I can get the custom rules reporting in Sonar?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This document has everything you need to write a custom rule in **Java** for **PMD v4.3**: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/howtowritearule.html

If it's possible it would also be good to update PMD to the latest 5.x version, configuration will be friendlier.

Let me know if this helped.